# How to decrypt this 13 rounds of AutoKey Cipher encryption question with Java/Python

Tags: java, encryption

This is the example for the **autokey cipher** used in my project:

In this project, **ciphertext** was generated by applying **autokey cipher**
multiple rounds.
• Note that in each round, the part concatenated to the key string is
brought from the result of the former round, not the original plaintext.

• **Example**

Primer key: feel

Plaintext: loveandpeace

(Round 1)

✓ Generated key string: feelloveandp

✓ Ciphertext: qszplbytenft

(Round 2)

✓ Generated key string: feelqszplbyt

✓ Ciphertext: vwdabtxipodm

• For this project, need to **find the original plaintext** from the given parts of the **plaintext and the ciphertext**.

• Ciphertext was generated by applying **13 rounds of autokey cipher**.

• Length of the primer key is 20, and the length of plaintext/ciphertext is 100.

• Assuming the question marks is unknown characters

**Plaintext:
DECRYPTINGACIPHERGEN????????????????????????????????????????????ISSOLVABLEWITHOU????????????????????**

**Ciphertext:
????????????????????RRAYLLEEDUIREFGHRSEPRRTXRYUO
WEVRRTUVSPROOLRZVSFOLINBLEJVGUOHTXNOJVAGTHEFECERGXRY**

This is the example of the solution i tried with **Java** but it does not work.

```
public class AutoKey {
public static String autoDecryption(String primerKey, String ciphertext) {
String decryptedText = "";

for (int round = 0; round < 13; round++) {
    String roundKey = primerKey + decryptedText;
    String roundDecryption = autoKeyDecryption(ciphertext, roundKey);

    // Log the intermediate results (optional)
    System.out.println("Round " + (round + 1) + " Key: " + roundKey);
    System.out.println("Round " + (round + 1) + " Decryption: " + roundDecryption);

    decryptedText = roundDecryption;
}

return decryptedText;
}

public static String autoKeyDecryption(String ciphertext, String key) {
    String decryptedText = "";
    String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

for (int i = 0; i < ciphertext.length(); i++) {
    int get1 = alphabet.indexOf(ciphertext.charAt(i));
    int get2;
    
    if (i < key.length()) {
        get2 = alphabet.indexOf(key.charAt(i));
    } else {
        get2 = alphabet.indexOf(decryptedText.charAt(i - key.length()));
    }

    int total = (get1 - get2) % 26;
    total = (total < 0) ? total + 26 : total;
    decryptedText += alphabet.charAt(total);
}

return decryptedText;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String primerKey = "DECRYPTINGACIPHERGEN";
    String ciphertext = "RRAYLLEEDUIREFGHRSEPRRTXRYUOWEVRRTUVSPROOLRZVSFOLINBLEJVGUOHTXNOJVAGTHEFECERGXRY";

String plaintext = autoDecryption(primerKey, ciphertext);

System.out.println("Original Plaintext: " + plaintext);
}

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: See [ask]. Do a preliminary debugging for each letter. And don't add unrelated tags. The security tag does not fit because you are implementing a toy cipher. The python tag does not fit because you are asking on Java code. The autokey tag does not fit because it's a framework for an automation.